# Luajit and Torch7 : accessing objects of type cdata from the Torch7 C api

Tags: c++, c, lua, luajit

Is there a way to convert **cdata** to **userdata**? How can I use the C api to push/retrieve **cdata** to/from the stack?

**Edit:** The original title mentioned luajit but not Torch. In that context the other answers beside the one I finally had submitted myself (*e.g* wolfgang's) made perfect sense.

Comment: Show concrete code and error messages, otherwise it didn't happen.

Comment: I don't have error messages, I just want to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Well thank you both. You have been extremely helpful.

Comment: @Ash So was your question.

Comment: To the people who have put this on hold: at the time the question was posted, the Torch7 c api was VERY poorly documented. It is still not very well documented today (Torch7 itself is, but the C api, not so much). I still think that the answer I posted can be helpful to a small number of people (I have redirected collegues to that post). Closing such a question as off-topic for a very well documented library such as openCV or Eigen would of course be appropriate, but I think that you should consider the state of the library in question before voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdata I was trying to access was the data of a tensor object from torch7, I finally found a way by using the torch7 C API, I will post it here just in case someone finds it useful:

```
#include <TH/TH.HW>
#include <TH/THStorage.h>
#include <TH/THTensor.h>
```

And then to get a tensor called "an_image" in the torch code:

```
lua_getglobal(L,"an_image");//assuming it goes on top of the stack
THDoubleTensor*data=(THDoubleTensor*)luaT_toudata(L,-1,"torch.DoubleTensor");
```

And finally given a buffer dest of doubles,

```
memcpy(dest,data->storage->data,n*sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no extension to the Lua C API to access cdata objects as created by LuaJIT's FFI library.

So, the simple and recommended way is to do your marshalling from the Lua side if you're dealing with cdata. So, call a C function from Lua and pass that `cdata` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll find useful information here: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html and more particularly here: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#convert_fromlua